# Usage of json_encode and json_decode

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents

I am new to PHP. I am using json_encode to convert an array into json data, and decode it using json_decode in another file. However, I am getting json error as syntax error.

My code is as follows:

**File 1:**

```
$result = get_data_array();

exit(json_encode($result));
```

**File 2:**

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://localhost/file1.php");
$data = json_decode($result,true);

$data->name // name is the array key
```

However, I am getting an error as:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: What kind of variable is `$data`? Try dumping it: `var_dump($data)`

Comment: @Jorge I tried that. Getting the result as null.

Comment: @Jorge, I m getting html data along with json encoded data. Is it due to the use of exit or file_get_contents?

Comment: Is http://localhost/file1.php outputting the correct data? As @nickb mentioned on the comments below, the script probably isn't getting the correct JSON.

Comment: Yes..even i think there is some mistake in the data i am receiving onto the second file..When i performed vardump of the data received, I got some HTML markup and after the markup was the valid JSON string...When I echoed the JSON encoded data in file1 it was valid JSON...

Comment: Post ALL of the outputs in your question. Specifically the output you're getting from `file1.php` (showing the HTML and then JSON).

Comment: If you have anything besides json on the file you're fetching, you won't get a valid json, even if it's only a misplaced comma. I'll guess you have html and json on the file, that's why the data can't be parsed. If that's the case, you can make an ajax request from that page instead of fetching the file using `file_get_contents()`, and the send the response from the same script you're fetching the json.

Comment: Make sure you are using a browser that allows you to see the JSON conversation in action, such as Chrome, or Firefox+Firebug. Often problems can be seen just by looking at this.

Answer (score 3):

You passed true to the second parameter of [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) so it will return an array.

Use this:

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://localhost/file1.php"); 
$data = json_decode($result,true);
echo $data['name'];
```

Comment: It should - If it's not then your original array doesn't contain the `name` key (or your script isn't pulling in the correct JSON)